# Pdfjs print button does not work with PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pdf.js, qprinter

Straight to issue, when pdf loads with pdfjs into pyqt5, seems print button does not work correctly, also the same for download button.

How could this bug be fixed?

The code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui, QtWebEngineWidgets

PDFJS = 'file:///pdfjs/web/viewer.html'
PDF = 'file:///file0.pdf'
class PdfReport(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(PdfReport, self).__init__(parent)
        self.load(QtCore.QUrl.fromUserInput('%s?file=%s' % (PDFJS, PDF)))  

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QtCore.QSize(640, 480)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    im = PdfReport()
    im.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Display:

[image]

Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The print task is not enabled in Qt WebEngine so the fault is displayed (I'm still trying to get the data). But in the case of the download button of the PDF it is possible and for this you must use the [`downloadRequested`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineprofile.html#downloadRequested) signal of the [`QWebEngineProfile`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineprofile.html):

```py
import os
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets

CURRENT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

PDFJS = QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(
    os.path.join(CURRENT_DIR, "pdfjs/web/viewer.html")
).toString()


class PdfReport(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(PdfReport, self).__init__(parent)
        QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineProfile.defaultProfile().downloadRequested.connect(
            self.on_downloadRequested
        )

    def load_pdf(self, filename):
        url = QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename).toString()
        self.load(QtCore.QUrl.fromUserInput("%s?file=%s" % (PDFJS, url)))

    def sizeHint(self):
        return QtCore.QSize(640, 480)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineDownloadItem)
    def on_downloadRequested(self, download):
        path, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(
            self, "Save File", "sample.pdf", "*.pdf"
        )
        if path:
            download.setPath(path)
            download.accept()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = PdfReport()
    path = os.path.join(CURRENT_DIR, "file0.pdf")
    w.load_pdf(path)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it works perfect. be kind to let me notify when you have solved the puzzle of print button function.

Comment: is there a way to intercept the signal that is emitted when the open file button is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

That's not a PyQt5 button, that is a button from your web view. It may not work because of your webView object or because the web part of your code lacks functionality for the button.

Comment: I do understand that's not pyqt5 button, have you tried to look [pdfjs online](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html) works fine, as soon as opens in PyQT5 it fails to do the job?

Comment: try to use PyQt5 browser, if you don't get the same problem it's an issue with PyQt's webView, if you still get the problem it a problem with the web part of your code or with PyQt's web interpretation